# Use the Xen HYPERVISOR_console_io hypercall

Tags: operating-system, osdev, xen

I am trying to make a Unikernel work as a Xen paravirtualized guest. I am currently working on a console driver but cannot get it to print any output. For debugging i would like to use the `HYPERVISOR_console_io` hypercall.

So i compiled Xen from Source with `--enable-debug` and `debug=y` options but i am unable to see any output whatsoever when i use this hypercall.

Can someone explain to me, what i have to do to see the messages i send via this hypercall?

Greetings Jan

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so i got this working. I had do add the following lines to my `/etc/defaults/grub` file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=hvc0 earlyprintk=xen"
GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN="com1=115200,8n1 console=vga,com1 sync_console"
```

Then `update-grub` and reboot.
If i connect to a serial console now, i can see the output of my hypercall like this:

```
xen@xen-001:~$ sudo xl create -c domain_config
Parsing config from domain_config
(d4) Hello!
xen@xen-001:~$ sudo xl destroy 4
```

Hope this helps someone too :-)

Greetings Jan